# External variable accessible and manipulatable by function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take a look at the following code.

```
import random
devicelist = ['a','a','a','a','a']

def generateconfig(tempconfiguration):
 global devicelist
 indexpositionzero = []
 indexpositionone = []
 for index in range(len(devicelist)):
  if tempconfiguration[index] == 1:
   indexpositionone.append(index)
  else:
   indexpositionzero.append(index)
 if len(indexpositionone) >= 3:
  godown = True
 elif len(indexpositionone) == 0:
  godown = False
 else:
  godown = random.randrange(0,2,1)
 if godown == True:
  index = random.randrange(0,len(indexpositionone),1)
  tempconfiguration[indexpositionone[index]] = 0
 if godown == False:
  index = random.randrange(0,len(indexpositionzero),1)
  tempconfiguration[indexpositionzero[index]] = 1
  return tempconfiguration

x = [1,0,1,0,1]
y = generateconfig(x)

print x
print y
```

Running this code will change x to the same value of y. Why is this happening? I'm not touching x at all! Such confuse! Please help.

Comment: Python variables are *references*. You passed in the list object `x` referenced, then altered that object in the function.

Comment: A list (mutable object) is passed by reference, so `tempconfiguration` is a reference to `x`.  Try passing `x[:]` instead.  See also `copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you have any idea how do I remove the reference? If say, I do a `newtempconfiguration = tempconfiguration` within the function and manipulate `newtempconfiguration`, `x` is still changed!

Comment: @myopenid: see [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802)

Comment: figured out another way to do this by  `for index in range(len(seperatecopyofconfiguration)):
  tempconfiguration.append(seperatecopyofconfiguration[index])`